# Radius of convergence of power series where power increases by increments of 2

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

I know that to determine the radius of convergence of the series
$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n $$
I need to find
$$ \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} \left| \frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k} \right| = c$$
Then the radius of convergence $R$
$$R = \frac{1}{c}$$
However how do I calculate the radius of a convergence for the series
$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^{2n} $$
Or more generally
$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^{Bn}, \quad B\in\mathbb{N} $$

Comment: $\sum a_{n} x^{2n} = \sum b_{n} x^{n}$ where $b_{n} = a_{n}$ if $n$ is even and $b_{n} = 0$ otherwise.

Comment: $\sum_n a_n x^{Bn} = \sum_n a_n (x^B)^n$, the radius of convergence would be $R^{1/B}$.

Comment: When you write $B\epsilon\mathbb N$ rather than $B\in\mathbb N,$ not only is the binary relation symbol different, but it doesn't have the same spacing to the right and left that is standard with binary relation symbols. Also, with \Sigma rather than \sum, you'll see $\displaystyle \Sigma_{n=1}^\infty$ rather than $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty.$ Hence my edits to this question. (In an inline context rather than a display, you see $\sum_{n=1}^\infty$ when \sum is used.)

Answer (score 4):

No, that's not what you need.  The Ratio Test is only one way to test convergence of a series.  It doesn't always work.  But in the case of a
series where some of the terms are zero, what might work is using the Ratio Test on consecutive **nonzero** terms.  Thus your series
$\sum_{n} a_n x^{Bn}$ converges if
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{|a_{n+1} x^{B(n+1)}|}{|a_n x^{Bn}|} = |x|^B \lim_{n \to\infty} \frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|} < 1$$
and diverges if that limit $> 1$.  If $\lim_{n \to \infty} |a_{n+1}|/|a_n| = c$ with $0 < c < \infty$, the radius of convergence is then $1/c^{1/B}$.

Answer (score 3):

For your problem, let $y=x^B$, so the series becomes $a_ny^n$ and the ratio test gives the radius of convergence for $y$ as $\frac{1}{c}$, so the radius of convergence for $x$ is $(\frac{1}{c})^\frac{1}{B}$.

Answer (score 2):

Use the root test:

$$\frac{1}{R} = \lim \sup |a_n^{1/n}|.$$

For the series:

$$S = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^{Bn}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty b_{k}x^{k}$$

with $$b_k = \left\{ \begin{aligned} &a_{k/B}, &k \textrm{ mod }B=0 \\ &0, &\textrm{ otherwise } \end{aligned} \right.$$

$$\frac{1}{R_S} = \lim \sup |b_k^{1/k}| = \lim \sup|a_{k/B}^{1/k}|=
\lim \sup|a_{n}^{\frac{1}{nB}}|=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} (|a_n|^{1/n})^\frac{1}{B}=c^{1/B}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Consider the series:

$\begin{equation*}
\sum_{n \ge 0} a_n x^{B n}
\end{equation*}$

From the respective theory, you know that for the series:

$\begin{equation*}
\sum_{n \ge 0} a_n y^n
\end{equation*}$

there is a *radius of convergence* $R$ such that it converges if $\lvert y \rvert < R$ and diverges whenever $\lvert y \rvert > R$. Now you can use the comparison test (pick $y_0$ so it is $\lvert y_0 \rvert < R$ and compare with the original series at $x_0 = y_0^{1/B}$ to prove convergence; pick a larger one to prove divergence similarly) to show that your original series converges if $\lvert x \rvert < R^{1/B}$ and diverges whenever $\lvert x \rvert > R^{1/B}$.